# Calculate product of transpositions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations

I've searched for this kind of question-answer, but didn't managed to find one because the problem is quite specific.

Let me explain:

I have permutation: $(13927)(5846)$ which I must write as product of transpositions.It is trivial.And the answer is $(13)(19)(12)(17)(58)(54)(56)$.
I can also multiply it to original form, which is once again trivial.So far so good.

But then I have this permutation, $(12)(13)(14)(15)(14)(13)(12)$ and instruction  to multiply it.
So what is the problem here? I basically, don't know how to multiply it back, because the pairs are repeating themselves. I have 2 times the pairs $(12),(13),(14)$ as you can observe...

I also know that $(12)*(12)$ yields identity but am not quite sure if this applies to the particular problem here, although it just might.

Could someone please shed some light on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just apply the transpositions to the numbers $1,...,5$. If you let $\pi=(12)(13)(14)(15)(14)(13)(12)$ You will find that $\pi(1) = 1$, $\pi(2) = 2$,$\pi(2) = 2$,$\pi(4) = 5$,$\pi(5) = 4$, hence $\pi = (45)$.

Another way is to note that $(14)(15)(14) = (45)$, and $(nm)^{-1} = (nm)$. Then $\pi = ((13)(12))^{-1} (45)( (13) (12))$. Since the $(45)$ and $(13)(12)$ have no overlap, we see that $\pi = ((13)(12))^{-1} ( (13) (12))(45) = (45)$.

**Addendum**: Note that a transposition of the form $(n_1...n_k)$ behaves as an identity for all values except $n_1,...,n_k$. Hence if we have two transpositions $(ab)$ and $(mn)$, where the $a,b,m,n$ are distinct, then we have $(ab)(mn) = (mn)(ab)$.

Furthermore, note that $(mn)(mn)$ is the identity, and it maps $m $ to $m$, $n$ to $n$ and is an identity for all other values.

Hence 
\begin{eqnarray}
\pi &=& (12)(13)(14)(15)(14)(13)(12) \\
&=& (12)(14)(13)(15)(14)(13)(12) \\
&=& (12)(14)(15)(13)(14)(13)(12) \\
&=& (12)(14)(15)(14)(13)(13)(12) \\
&=& (12)(14)(15)(14)(12) \\
&=& (14)(12)(15)(14)(12) \\
&=& (14)(15)(12)(14)(12) \\
&=& (14)(15)(14)(12)(12) \\
&=& (14)(15)(14) \\
&=& (45)
\end{eqnarray}
To see where the last two lines come from, note that the only values affected by $\sigma=(14)(15)(14)$ are $1,4,5$, other values are mapped to themselves. We note (by computation) that $\sigma(1) = 1, \sigma(4) = 5$ and $\sigma(5) = 4$, hence $\sigma = (45)$.

**Note**: To compute $\pi = \pi_1 \cdots \pi_k$, just compute $\pi(n)$ for all $n$. For example, if $\pi = \pi_1 \pi_2 \pi_3  = (14)(15)(14)$ is applied to $(1,2,3,4,5)$, we can do it step by step as in (excuse the abuse of notation)  $\pi_1 (1,2,3,4,5) = (4,2,3,1,5)$, $\pi_2(4,2,3,1,5) = (4,2,3,5,1)$ and
$\pi_3 (4,2,3,5,1) = (1,2,3,5,4)$. Hence $\pi$ just swaps $4,5$ and so we can write $\pi = (45)$.

Comment: Ok.Let me see if I get it.
We basically note that $(12)(13)$*$(13)(12)$ is a identity.
Then we note that we are left with $(14)$(15)$(14)$ which is then $(45)$.
But I am not sure how do I get the $(45)$ from $(14)$(15)$(14)$

Comment: @Satoshi: I added more explanation to the answer.

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand 90% of it.Your addendum made your answer better, but why can't you do this?:
$=(14)(15)(14)$
$=(14)(14)(15)$

And also, I can't see the mechanics of multiplying this $=(14)(15)(14)$ .

Also what is the rule of moving transpositions from left to right in your addendum?

Comment: The rule is that if the numbers in two pairs do not overlap, then they commute. However, the numbers in $(14)$ and $(15)$ do overlap (both have 1), so they do not necessarily commute. If you just compute the permutations, you will see that $(14)(15)(14) = (45)$, but $(14)(14)(15) = (15)$.

Comment: I added a note showing how I computed $(14)(15)(14)$.

Comment: Glad to help!${}{}$

Answer (score 1):

Note that we can just see these transpositions as "maps" on the set $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$.

So, what does multiplication of transpositions mean in this setting?
Well, it's just composition of these maps.

So, $(1 2)$ means the map that takes $1$ to $2$, $2$ to $1$, and fixes everything else. Thus $(1 3)(1 2)$ takes $1$ to $2$, $2$ to $3$ and $3$ to $1$ Thus $(1 3)(1 2)=(1 2 3).$

Can you proceed now?